# Unable to export an async function under a module to other file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, import, export

I am working on a project where all of my files are stated under the json object notation, I declared an async function under one object and I want to export that function from the specific file to other file. The file is called as test2.js

with code as:-

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const test={
    browser:null,
    page:null,
    initial:async () => {
        test.browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
         test.page = await test.browser.newPage();
await test.page.goto('https://www.safari.com/');
// await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});
async function dostuff(){
let h1;
try{
             h1=await test.page.evaluate(()=>{
let h = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
return {
                    h
                }
            });
let heading = h1.h
return heading;
        }catch(err){
return `Sorry the value is not been permited`
        }

    }
//const h =  Promise.resolve(dostuff()).then(head =>console.log(head))
//this is working fine
// Promise.resolve(dostuff()).then(head =>console.log(head))
await dostuff()
      },
}

module.exports = test //Here I don't kind of know how to call the function as with module.exports.dostuff = this.dostuff is also not working ...
```

I want to call this function on second file called as test_result.js

which is like :

```
const helper = require('./test2')
async function node(){
await helper.initial()
await Promise.resolve(helper.dostuff()).then(head =>console.log(head))

}
node()
```

The error in the code on runtime is "helper.dostuff" is not a function

Any ideas on how can I run the code to get the data from the element on specified time or at run

Comment: You defined `doStuff` within `initial()`, not as part of the `test` object, that's why it's not found. Proper indentation will help.

Answer (score 0):

the helper.dostuff is not a function error is being solved by

```
 module.exports.dostuff = this.dostuff
```

But

```
Promise.resolve(helper.dostuff).then(head =>console.log(head))
```

on test_result.js file is showing undefined
Don't Know how to fix this on time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

export the test object @test2.js:

```
export const test = { //your code with 'initial' method/prop };
```

import the test object @test_result.js:

```
import { test } from './filepath_of_test2.js'
```

function call/execution @test_result.js:

```
async someFunction = () => {
  await test.initial();
}

someFunction();
```